# Filtering out emoticons using sed

Tags: regex, sed, grep, emoticons

I have a grep expression using cygwin grep on Win.

```
grep -a "\\,,/\|\\m/\|\\m/\\>\.</\\m/\|:u" all_fbs.txt > rockon_fbs.txt
```

Once I identify the emoticon class, however, I want to strip them out of the data. However, the same regexp above within a sed results in a syntax error (yes, I realize I could use /d instead of //g, but this doesn't make a difference, I still get the error.)

```
sed "s/\(\\,,/\|\\m/\|\\m/\\>\.</\\m/\|:u\)*//g"
```

The full line is:

```
grep -a "\\,,/\|\\m/\|\\m/\\>\.</\\m/\|:u" all_fbs.txt | sed "s/\(\\,,/\|\\m/\|\\m/\\>\.</\\m/\|:u\)*//g" | sed "s/^/ROCKON\t/" > rockon_fbs.txt
```

The result is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

I know it's coming from the sed regexp I'm asking about it b/c if I remove that portion of the full line, then I get no error (but, of course, the emoticons are not filtered out).

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: Hm, filter out emoticons?  Is it related to [this product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890760)? :-)

Comment: No, it isn't. If you're really curious, this is related to an AI class where I need to label some data to train a classifier, but obviously I don't want the classifier to learn the emoticons upon which I'm basing the labels! :)

Comment: You can probably get `sed` to do what `grep` is doing and combine the two calls to `sed`: `sed -n  '/selector/ { s/.../.../g; s/^/.../; p }' > ...` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `/` otherwise it will prematurely terminate the expression.

```
s/\(\\,,/\|\\m/\|\\m/\\>\.</\\m/\|:u\)*//g
        ^     ^     ^      ^   ^
          These need escaping.
```

You should also use single-quoted strings instead of double-quoted strings to prevent the backslashes being interpreted by the shell:

```
$ echo "\\,"
\,
$ echo '\\,'
\\,
```

So try this:

```
$ echo 'foo \m/ bar \,,/ baz' | sed 's/\(\\,,\/\|\\m\/\|\\m\/\\>\.<\/\\m\/\|:u\)*//g'
foo  bar  baz
```

Comment: Thanks so much! The non-escape-age of the / was the problem. Much appreciated!

Comment: Alternatively, don't use `/` as separators in sed. e.g. `sed 's;foo;bar;'`